# Script running from terminal but not in crontab

Tags: bash, cron, cp

My problem is the following:

I've made a script called `copy.sh` in the `/var/etc` folder in order to copy some `.cfg` files from there to `myfiles`

```
#!/bin/bash
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
cp *.cfg /usr/local/myfiles/
```

When I run it from a terminal, the script does the job but 
in `crontab` it's not working:

```
*/1 * * * * /bin/sh /var/etc/copy.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

The crontab log is fine because when I do a:

```
grep CRON /var/log/syslog
```

I see this:

```
Aug 11 14:01:01 vmixxx25 /USR/SBIN/CRON[14840]: (root) CMD (/bin/sh /var/etc/copy.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 &)
```

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: cron does not have many environment variables. So it is probably not finding the files in `*.cfg`. You should use full paths so that it can find them.

Comment: While running in `cron` remove `SHELL` and `PATH` lines, its of no use in your case..in the command remove `&` from the end as `cron` itself runs in the background..also does the `.cfg` files reside in `/var/etc` ?

Comment: yes .cfg file resides on /var/etc

Comment: You haven't changed the directory, so `cp` won't be running in `/var/etc`. You have redirected all output to null, and send the program to background, so there is no output for cron to log. What did you expect?

Comment: There is no reason for setting SHELL or the PATH or ever, in cron, the she-bang (#!/bin/bash). Then, after setting the shell, you call it with sh. In cron your entire "script" is a one liner and you need to use the full path. You are making this more complicated then it needs to be.

Comment: @ bodhi.zazen i am here to ask for a solution, i am not here to criticize me..if you knew how it is done you should have told me like user A.B did..Nevertheless problem is solved with users A.B help..Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script runs, there is just one problem: use an absolute path in your script:

```
cp /path/to/*.cfg /usr/local/myfiles/
```

`cron` knows nothing about the location of your `.cfg` files and therefore copies nothing.

To improve your crontab, simply replace your line with the line below. You don't need a script for that.

```
*/1 * * * * cp /path/to/*.cfg /usr/local/myfiles >/dev/null 2>&1
```

**Warning** the command will be started every minute!

Comment: Use that as a "one liner" in cron. Your "script" is (sorry to say) sloppy and completely unnecessary as noted by several in the comments to your question. If the answer is updated I would upvote it.

Comment: is not that cron knows nothing about the location of the cfg files, but the fact that the relative references are not understood because its "home" path is probably `/`.

Comment: @ A.B I know it will be started every minute..it was done as an example time to check if is running.. now script has change to cp /var/etc/*.cfg /usr/local/myfiles and crontab is */1 * * * * /bin/sh /var/etc/copy.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 & and is running fine..